# Why does an output string show data I never wrote?

Tags: c, output

I'm writing a program that encrypts a file by adding 10 to each character. Somehow a portion of the programs working directory is being printed to the file, and I have no idea why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main(void){
        FILE *fp;
        fp=fopen("tester.csv","r+");
        Encrypt(fp);      
        fclose(fp);
    }

    int Encrypt(FILE *fp){
        int offset=10;
        Shift(fp, offset);
    }
    int Decrypt(FILE *fp){
        int offset= -10;
        Shift(fp, offset);
    }
    int Shift(FILE *fp, int offset){
        char line[50],tmp[50], character;
        long position;
        int i;
        position = ftell(fp);
        while(fgets(line,50,fp) != NULL){
            for(i=0;i<50;i++){
                character = line[i];
                character = (offset+character)%256;
                tmp[i] = character; 
                if(character=='\n' || character == 0){break;}                
            }
            fseek(fp,position,SEEK_SET);
            fputs(tmp,fp);
            position = ftell(fp);
            fseek(stdin,0,SEEK_END);
        }
      }
```

the file originally reads

```
this, is, a, test
i, hope, it, works!
```

after the program is run:

```
~rs}6*s}6*k6*~o}~
/alexio/D~6*y|u}+
k6*~o}~
/alexio/D
```

where users/alexio/Desktop is part of the path. How does this happen???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you "encode" the string, it won't be null terminated (that's your case), or it will contain a null even before the end of the string (character+offset % 256 == 0). Later you try to write it as a string, which overruns your buffer, and outputs part of your program arguments.

Use [`fread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread) and [`fwrite`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fwrite).

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
fputs(tmp,fp);
```

writes out a probably non-null terminated string. So it continues to copy memory to the file until it finds a null.

You need to add a null to the end of 'tmp' in the case where the loop breaks on a newline.

Comment: your solution has some flaws, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

A number of things:

1. You're encoding all 50 chars from your read buffer, regardless of how many were actually read with [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/). Recall that [`fgets()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fgets/) reads a **line**, not an entire buffer (unless the line is longer than a buffer, and your's is *not*). Anything past the string length from your line file input is stack garbage.
2. You're then dumping all that extra garbage data, andbeyond, by not terminating your `tmp[]` string before writing with `fputs()` which you should not be using anyway. Yet-more stack garbage.

Solution. Use [**`fread()`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fread/) and [**`fwrite()`**](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fwrite/) for this encoding. There is no reason to be using string functions whatsoever. When you write your *decoder* you'll thank yourself for using `fread()` and `fwrite()`